# Force Centos Docker Image to Use European Mirrors

Tags: networking, yum, docker, repository

I'm trying to build a Centos Docker Image to run NFIQ-2. It has the docker file listed above.

```
################################################################################
#
#   Builder environnement
#
################################################################################

FROM centos as builder
LABEL maintainer "Marco.DeDonno@unil.ch"
RUN sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
ADD NFIQ2.tgz /

RUN yum update && \
    yum upgrade -y

RUN yum group install -y "Development Tools" && \
    yum install -y cmake

RUN cd /NFIQ2/libOpenCV && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make /NFIQ2/OpenCV/

RUN make -C /NFIQ2/libOpenCV \
    opencv_core opencv_ts opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_flann \
    opencv_features2d opencv_calib3d opencv_ml opencv_video opencv_objdetect \
    opencv_contrib opencv_nonfree opencv_gpu opencv_photo opencv_stitching opencv_videostab

RUN make -C /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib:/NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib

################################################################################
#
#   Running environnement
#
################################################################################

FROM centos

COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/bin/ /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/bin/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib/ /NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib/ /NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib/ /NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib/

COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/complianceTestSet/ /NFIQ2/complianceTestSet/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib
```

Still when I run it I cannot seem to find the packages on the repos:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update &&     yum upgrade -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The maintainer of the package says the repos yum is getting for me miss the files but how do I select other repos in the docker image?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the update command did the trick to just     RUN  yum update:

```
FROM centos as builder
LABEL maintainer "Marco.DeDonno@unil.ch"
RUN sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
ADD NFIQ2.tgz /

#RUN yum update && \
#    yum upgrade -y
RUN  yum update

RUN yum group install -y "Development Tools" && \
    yum install -y cmake

RUN cd /NFIQ2/libOpenCV && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make /NFIQ2/OpenCV/

RUN make -C /NFIQ2/libOpenCV \
    opencv_core opencv_ts opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_flann \
    opencv_features2d opencv_calib3d opencv_ml opencv_video opencv_objdetect \
    opencv_contrib opencv_nonfree opencv_gpu opencv_photo opencv_stitching opencv_videostab

RUN make -C /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib:/NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib

################################################################################
#
#   Running environnement
#
################################################################################

FROM centos

COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/bin/ /NFIQ2/NFIQ2/bin/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib/ /NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib/ /NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib/
COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib/ /NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib/

#COPY --from=builder /NFIQ2/complianceTestSet/ /NFIQ2/complianceTestSet/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/NFIQ2/libOpenCV/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/common/lib:/NFIQ2/biomdi/fingerminutia/lib
```